# Get all the transferred RadListBox items on Label & bind a RadGrid using RadListBox_items, ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, radgrid, radlistbox

**1.)** I am using below code to transfer items from one `RadListBox` to another.

**HTML code:**

```
A<telerik:RadListBox ID="RadListBox1" runat="server" Width="250px" Height="200px" 
 TransferMode="Move" AllowTransfer="True" TransferToID="rlbGI_BU" SelectionMode="Multiple"
 OnTransferred="RadListBox1_Transferred" 
 AutoPostBackOnTransfer="true">
</telerik:RadListBox>
B<telerik:RadListBox ID="RadListBox2" runat="server" Width="250px" Height="200px"
 EnableEmbeddedSkins="False" Skin="MetroRed" ImagesPath="../App_Themes/MetroRed/ListBox"
 OnInserted="RadListBox2_Inserted" SelectionMode="Multiple"
 OnDeleted="RadListBox2_Deleted" AutoPostBackOnDelete="true">
</telerik:RadListBox>
<br />
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblDeletedList2"></asp:Label> &nbsp; &nbsp;
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblInsertedList2"></asp:Label> &nbsp; &nbsp;
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTransdList1"></asp:Label> &nbsp; &nbsp;
```

**C# code:**

```
private string _SPID = null;
private DataTable _dtSPBU = null;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _SPID = Request.QueryString["SPID"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_SPID))
    {
        _dtSPBU = SDM.SPBU.GetSPBUBySPBUfoSPID(_SPID);
    }
}

protected void bind_RadListBox1()
{
    RadListBox1.DataTextField = "BUName";
    RadListBox1.DataValueField = "SPBUfoBUID";
    RadListBox1.DataSource = _dtSPBU;
    RadListBox1.DataBind();
}

protected void RadListBox2_Inserted(object sender, RadListBoxEventArgs e)
{
    ArrayList myTest = new ArrayList();
    //StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < e.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        myTest.Add(rlbGI_BU.Items[i].Text);

        foreach (string x in myTest)
        {
                lblInsertedList2.Text += x + ", " + "&nbsp;";
        }
    } 
}

protected void RadListBox2_Deleted(object sender, RadListBoxEventArgs e)
{
    lblDeletedList2.Text += e.Items.Count.ToString() + " items are deleted";
}

protected void RadListBox1_Transferred(object sender, RadListBoxTransferredEventArgs e)
{       
    lblTransdList1.Text += e.Items.Count.ToString() + " items are transferred";
}
```

I want to get the transferred Items from `RadListBox1` to `RadListBox2` inside a `Label` control (say `lblInsertedList2` Label) because later I have to bind a `RadGrid` based on the Items that are inside RadListBox2.
For this, I created `RadListBox2_Inserted` event, inside which I am trying to get the items of `RadListBox2` in Label.
Now, When I transfer more than 1 items of RadListBox1 to RadListBox2 (using ctrl button), then the 1st selected item is repeated.

*Eample:* 
RadListBox1 has "a","b","c" items.
when I transfer all "a","b","c" together from RadListBox1 to RadListBox2 (using ctrl button)

I see the below output: a a b a b c

Correct output should be: a b c

Please check below snapshot for above issue:
[image]
Again, RadListBox1 has "a","b","c" items
when I transfer items 1 by 1 from RadListBox1 to RadListBox2

*Eample:* 
when I only transfer a, I see below output: a (1st time)
when I only transfer b, I see below output: a, a (2nd time)
when I only transfer c, I see below output: a, a, a (3rd time)

Please check below snapshot for above issue:
[image]

**2.)** I want to bind a `RadGrid` using:

- _SPID = Request.QueryString["SPID"]
- Items getting in RadListBox2 (only selected items from RadListBox1)

right now I am binding `RadGrid` using only `Request.QueryString["SPID"]`, so I get all the data related to "SPID"

*Example:*

> SPID      RadListBox1_Items     Value
>
> 014            a                           test1
>   014            b                           test2
>   014            c                           test3

**My requirement is:** If suppose in `RadListBox2` got only 2 items "a" , "c"
then the data in `RadGrid` shall bind based on RadListBox2 items and "SPID"

> SPID      RadListBox2_Items     Value
>
> 014            a                           test1
>   014            c                           test3

I hope I made my requirement clear. Please let me know if any confusion. Please do reply for both the points.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the for - loop in the Inserted event makes the problem...

Comment: @SankarRaj: Thank you for the reply. I am getting correct record in `e.Items.Count` so what shall I change in it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that below code will fulfill your Requirement

```
protected void RadListBox2_Inserted(object sender, RadListBoxEventArgs e)
{
    ArrayList myTest = new ArrayList();
    //StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < e.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        myTest.Add(e.Items[i].Text);    

    } 
     foreach (string x in myTest)
        {
                lblInsertedList2.Text += x + ", " + "&nbsp;";
        }
}
```

OR simply

```
protected void RadListBox2_Inserted(object sender, RadListBoxEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < e.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        lblInsertedList2.Text += e.Items[i].Text + ", " + "&nbsp;";
    } 

}
```

Hopes it helps...